# How to check if an interface have a function implementation in Go?

Tags: go, interface

I have a constructor that returns an interface. There are cases when that interface does not have actual implementation of some of its functions. Trying to call these unemplemented functions causes panic. I want to know is there a way to check is it safe to call a function or not, before actually calling it.

Here is the [setup](https://go.dev/play/p/JBSGAficlIY).

```
package main

type i interface {
    Foo()
    Bar()
}

type s struct {
    i
}

func (r s) Foo() {}

func main() {
    var ii i = &s{}
    ii.Foo() // OK
    ii.Bar() // will panic
}
```

Comment: An interface is a _method set_, you cannot use a function, and you cannot have an unimplemented method.

Comment: @JimB despite the fact I can. 

Here is the safe implementation of that check I was looking for: https://go.dev/play/p/u2aojdYAz4-

Answer (score 0):

The type `s` embeds an interface variable. Any call to interface methods not explicitly declared by `s` will panic because the embedded interface is nil. You should set that before calling the methods:

```
var ii i=&s{}
ii.i=<implementation of i>
```

So, it is not that the type `s` unimplemented methods. The type `s` delegates its method implementations to `i`, which is nil.